# i want a style to my id="checkimg" by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**JavaScript**

```
if ((valid1 && valid2 && valid3 && valid4 && valid5 && valid6 && valid7 && valid8)==1)
{
    // here i want to put image in my given ID.
    document.formElem.next1.disabled=false;
} else {
    document.formElem.next1.disabled=true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <li id="checkimg">Personal</li>
```

**CSS**

```
background:transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left;
```

i want the the above style to my id i.e. `id="checkimg"` if in javascript if condition is true , so what is the code i have to put there in if condition?

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? or even PHP ... not sure you selected the correct tags !

Comment: Have you done any research at all, and do you have any programming experience besides javascript?

Comment: i am using javascript , but any solution in jquery most welcome.

Comment: I don't trust the `==1` in the first line. Are you sure you know how the `&&` operator works in Javascript?

Comment: no problem with ==1 and && it working fine..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
document.getElementById('checkimg').style.background = "transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checking").css({'background':'transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left'});
```

or

```
$("#checking").css({'background':'transparent url(../images/checked.png)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-position': 'top left'});
```

Answer (score -1):

hi if you are using jQuery then

```
$("#checking").css({'background':'transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left;'});
```

if you are using javascript then try:

```
if ((valid1 && valid2 && valid3 && valid4 && valid5 && valid6 && valid7 && valid8)==1)
{ 
     var obj = document.getElementById("checkimg");
    **EDIT**
     obj.style.background = "background:transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left";

    document.formElem.next1.disabled=false;

}
    else
        document.formElem.next1.disabled=true;
```

EDIT 2: - 
you can also create a css class:

```
.bgimg{background:transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left;}
```

and add the Attribute to the obj.

```
obj.setAttribute("class", "bgimg"); // inside your condition, remember u get the obj using getElementById
```

Comment: obj.setAttribute("style", "background:transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left;"); // this line may have same error , javascript is not executing after this line...

Comment: try this then `obj.style.background = "transparent url(../images/checked.png) no-repeat top left";`

Comment: ok no probs, just check `var obj=document.getElementById("checkimg");` check the case for `document.getElementById`

Comment: Id("checkimg") its <li>'s id , so think <li> dont have value.

 <li id="checkimg">Personal</li>